# C++20 modules on clang (Windows): typeinfo error in simplest example

Tags: c++, visual-studio, module, c++20

File `first_module.cppm`

```
export module first_module;

int foo(int x) {
  return x;
}

export int e = 42;

export int bar() {
  return foo(e);
}
```

Pre-compiling (no problems):

```
$ clang++ --std=c++20 -fmodules --precompile first_module.cppm -o first_module.pcm
```

Compiler information:

```
$ clang++ -v
clang version 10.0.0
Target: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
```

File `first-main.cc`

```
import first_module;

int main() {
  return bar();
}
```

Compiling (no problems):

```
$ clang++ --std=c++20 -fmodules first-main.cc -fmodule-file=first_module.pcm first_module.pcm
```

Everything is ok.

File `second-main.cc`

```
import first_module;

#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::cout << bar() << std::endl;
}
```

Compiling same way:

```
$ clang++ --std=c++20 -fmodules second-main.cc -fmodule-file=first_module.pcm first_module.pcm
```

Result: **ton** of errors like:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\include\eh.h:56:14: error: reference to 'type_info' is ambiguous
        _In_ type_info const&     _Type,
             ^
note: candidate found by name lookup is 'type_info'
note: candidate found by name lookup is 'type_info'
```

I have feeling that I am doing something wrong, because I have newest MSVS (updated recently), newest clang, but something still not working on Windows on trivial examples.

Or may be this is known bug? Tried to google it, no results.

Comment: Clang (or any other compiler) currently only has partial support for C++ 20 modules. Work on the new standard isn't finished yet. I don't know if this particular code is already supposed to work, but you can't really use modules and expect everything to work yet.

Comment: Still under Ubuntu everything works for the same version of clang...

Comment: then your issue is something else. I just wanted to point it out. That's why i didnt post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core problem resides in that your current `Clang` installation it's working with the `MSVC` toolchain and there's a known issue when you compile using `#include` directives with the Microsoft toolchain with `Clang` using the `modules` feature.

You can find it here, opened since 2018
https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/38400

Comment: Again: linking with MSVS toolchain is an essential part of question. Using any other toolchain is not an option. Thanks for the link, btw. I think it worth updating your answer with this link, deleting gcc toolchain mentions and I will remove downvote and accept.

Comment: It's done. Didn't notice that you only want use the msvc toolchain. Btw, the gcc one also presents issues with the system headers. Best option under windows with Clang w'd be probably use WSL. Or directly, use the MSVC as compiler. I am trying some alternatives to Clang under Windows, but I feel more confortable with the LLVM techs.

Comment: Thanks! Will track this. Haven't found this link myself.